# Online Mussar and Gemara Shiurim in Yiddish?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, adult-learning, yiddish

I have noticed that most resources for learning Yiddish are of a decidedly secular/conversational nature. Personally, I would rather immerse myself in the language by listening to a shiur (preferably on gemara or mussar) that's given in it. Unfortunately, such a thing does not exist where I live, and I was wondering if anybody knows of any Yiddish-language shiurim on such subjects that can be downloaded? I have stumbled across a few, but they were recorded in the middle of the 20th century and are of very poor audio quality.

Comment: Is "online" enough, or is "downloadable" a requirement? Because YouTube has plenty that satisfy the former but not the latter. (A quick search found the [Kol haLashon in Yiddish channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/kolhalashon1), for instance, which has many Yiddish gemara shiurim.)

Answer (score 3):

[Kol Avraham](http://www.kolavrohom.com/index.asp) has Daf Yomi shiurim in Yiddish. The recordings I sampled seem to have a bit of echo, but were otherwise of decent quality.

Comment: Thankyou - that's awesome. I wonder if there's software for stripping it of the echo? I don't want to be overly picky, but I am finding it a bit hard to differentiate his words from one another.

Comment: @ShimonbM That'susuallytrueofafluentspeaker. It's what I find hardest about understanding Hebrew. (In other words, I don't know that removing the echo will help much.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Lubavitcher Rebbe, there's a lot of him speaking Yiddish. You kind of have to poke around but start here: 
http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/default_cdo/aid/591213/jewish/Jewishtv.htm
http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/1743851/jewish/Video.htm
http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/livingtorah/player_cdo/
http://www.thelivingarchive.org/categories
http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/sichoskodesh.htm
http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/sichoskodesh_cdo/jewish/Sichos-Kodesh.htm
http://videos.jemedia.org/

http://www.chassidus.com/audio/s/

This one is really excellent: http://www.chabad.org/therebbe/sichoskodesh.htm

http://www.770live.com/en770/sichos/SichosKodesh.asp?lang=1# -- See bottom left "Shiurim" section for Yiddish shiurim on the Daf. Also includes some other Lubavitch material in Yiddish

http://yagdiltorah.org/html/links.htm

torahcafe.com -- search "Yiddish"

More balabatish and organized set of resources (including Yiddish audio), if you're willing to disburse money: http://www.jemstore.com/default.asp

Not Lubavitch:
http://www.hadarhatorah.org/pages/audio.php  (search the page for "Yiddish")

Apologies for the big geniza of random stuff (and for the randomness of some of these websites themselves) but that is often how you find good things, which task I'll leave to you :)

Comment: How good is the audio quality? The OP specifically said that Shiurim from the mid 20th century which he heard had poor audio quality.

Comment: @DoubleAA Naturally, it varies. Chabad has remastered some of them, though. I'll readily admit that this was not my most useful answer

Answer (score 1):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe (the seventh rebbe of Chabad) Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson conducted most all of his shiurim in Yiddish. Most people have bad sentiments against Chabad-Lubavitch so you mind not find these useful to your purposes. Here's a link to them though if you're interested: [The Farbrengen Series](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/2143216/jewish/The-Farbrengen-Series.htm/mobile/false)

(YouTube also has a few recordings, mostly people recording from a smartphone though.)

The audio quality in The Farbrengen Series is pretty nice in my opinion, unlike other films of the Rebbe which have horrible quality. As for the YouTube ones, you win some you lose some with audio quality.

Comment: How good is the audio quality? The OP specifically said that Shiurim from the mid 20th century which he heard had poor audio quality.

Comment: That info should be in your answer to help people.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really "online," but you can hear Yiddish shiurim 24/7, maybe 24/6, over the telephone at this number: (718) 735-7333. (Numbers to call outside Brooklyn, NY are listed [here](http://www.chassidus.com/phone/).)

The audio quality is not great, and they speak fast, but you get used to it.